# greendao delete from db and session

Tags: android, greendao

I'm using greendao for a android project and wanted to know how to properly delete and object from the db and from the session cache.  Currently I do the following to delete from the db:

```
ChatDao chatDao = daoSession.getChatDao();
chatDao.queryBuilder().buildDelete().executeDeleteWithoutDetachingEntities();
```

However as the method name and documentation state this may leave stale objects in the session cache, how can I remove the objects from there too?

Answer (score 9):

In order to clear cached objects in your DaoSession use this call:

```
DaoSession.clear();
```

It will clear all objects in your session identity scope.

Answer (score 5):

As Anatoliy described, you can use DaoSession.clear(). However, it will clear all all objects from the session. If you want to avoid that, you have to execute a regular query and delete the result entities (for example with deleteInTx).

Comment: Can I not delete the cached objects of a specific entity instead of ALL cached objects ? For example doing something like this : **ChatDao.clear ()** ?