# Android GreenDao - Delete cached objects of a specific entity only

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I am using GreenDao ORM in my Android application.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387961/greendao-delete-from-db-and-session) , one can use

```java
DaoSession.clear();
```

in order to clear **ALL** cached objects of the session.

My question is : How about clearing the cached objects of a **specific entity** (instead of all) ? How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be `dao.detachAll()` in the next release. The commit is here:
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/commit/6a658c84e7de97073a260e062b06e3cc13a18196

Side note: use `yourDao.detach(yourEntity)` to remove a single entity from the identity scope. This forces subsequent queries for this database object to return a different object.

Comment: Did you do that? The feature is still missing and I could not find an existing issue. I added a new one: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/286